# Jmeter threadNum function returns "StandardJMeterEngine"

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use threadNum function in `JMeter (2.13)` but whenever I use it in `"User Defined Variable" as ${__threadNum()}`, it returns

> "StandardJMeterEngine"

.

Isn't it supposed to return thread number??

Is this correct behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is designed to be inlined in the test script, like:

[image: ThreadNum demo]

See [Using JMeter Functions - Part II](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) guide for more information on this and other JMeter functions

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri. Then.. is there any way to use thread number as variable? I'd like to use thread number as username along with a prefix..

Comment: Oh I got it. I just need to use it inside ThreadGroup. Thanks!